# what's Mistake did calculate determinat??

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let:
$$A＝\begin{pmatrix} 1& 1 &1\\2 & 1&1\\1&0&2\end{pmatrix}
$$

and we have :
$$\text{det}(A)＝\begin{vmatrix} 1& 1 &1\\2 & 1&1\\1&0&2\end{vmatrix}＝\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1\\0 & 2\end{vmatrix}-\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 1 \\1& 2\end{vmatrix}＋\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 1\\1 & 0\end{vmatrix}＝-1
$$

but using wolfram alpha : $\text{det}(A)=-2$

**Thank you for all**

Comment: $2-3-1=-2$. Double-check your $2\times2$ determinants. Edit: with apologies to those who beat me to it.

Comment: $2-3-1=-2$ so it's basic arithmetic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to have just made a mistake in calculating the last step (with the $2\times 2$ determinants). We have
$$
\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 2
\end{vmatrix} - \begin{vmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 2
\end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{vmatrix}
&= \left(1\times 2 - 1 \times 0\right) - \left(2\times 2 - 1\times 1\right) + \left(2\times 0 - 1 \times 1 \right)\\
&= \left(2 - 0\right) - \left(4 - 1\right) + \left(0 - 1\right) \\
&= 2 - 3 - 1 \\
&= -2.
\end{align*}
$$